# adding onsubmit to drupal login forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

the default login form in drupal doesn't have any javascript to check whether the fields(Username and password) are empty or not before submitting the form.
so, i want to add it onsubmit to the user login form..how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to just create a module that adds a .js file (via drupal_add_js()) that does something like this (note: the classes here are just a guess, didn't check the actual class names):

```
$('.login-form .form-submit').click(function() {
    // your error checking here
});
```

Comment: True, but don't forget to wrap that in the well known jQuery: $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: Actually, $(document).ready isn't recommended for modules. Instead, use a behavior: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--javascript_startup_guide.html/6#drupal-js-api

Answer (score 0):

please read how to theme login block: http://drupal.org/node/19855

And attach to submit button one of these javascript functions:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php